# how to exclude .html and add / at the end of the url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

i have this `htaccess` code that removes the `.html` extension for my URL, but i want to add / at the end of the URL after the `.html` extension is removed, how to i do that?
here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: The slash at the end would indicate your file is now a directory and not a file. Are you sure that is what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

However this rule doesn't remove `.html` extension from URLs , it just makes it so that you can type `exampe.com/file` instead of `example.com/file.html` in browser address bar. If you want to remove `html`  extension from URLs you can use the following complete rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
#redirect /file.html to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [L,R=301]
#internally map /file to /file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: i ant the url to change from `example.com/file.html` to `example.com/file/` not `example.com/file` and sorry for the confusion on marking the answer correct

Comment: @orenzofoods The rule already does it. Please test it on your server. It's working perfectly fine for me on Apache